# Python random random

Tags: python, random

```
if Airplane==1:
 while icounter<4:
    ifuelliter=random.randrange(1,152621)
    #litter/kilometer
    LpK=152620/13500
    km=LpK*ifuelliter


    ipca=random.randrange(0,50)
    ipcb=random.randrange(0,50)
    ipcc=random.randrange(0,812)







    #3D space distance calculation
    idstance= math.sqrt((icba-ipca)**2 + (icbb-ipcb)**2 + (icbc-ipcc)**2)

    totaldist=km-idstance

    if totaldist>0:
          print "You have enoph fuel to get to New York AirPort"
          print ipca1,ipcb2,ipcc3
          icounter=3

    if totaldist<=0:

         print "You dont have enoph fuel to get to New York AirPort please go to the nearest one or you will die"
         print ipca,ipcb,ipcc
         icounter=icounter+1`
```

How can I make that

```
ipca=random.randrange(0,50)
ipcb=random.randrange(0,50)
ipcc=random.randrange(0,812)
```

the random number every time will go down in loop and not every time other number. 
For example:
no:

```
812
512
321
815
600
700
```

Yes:

```
800
600
550
320
50
1
```

Comment: please try expressing what you need again.

Comment: i need that the random numbers wil random down all the time for example

no:
900
511
11
865
0
165
980
1000
10010

Yes
800
600
400
250
10
2
1
0

Answer (score 2):

If you want your random numbers to be decreasing, but you still want a uniform distribution of them, you really need to generate all the values up front, then sort them into descending order:

```
xs = [random.randrange(0, 50) for _ in range(4)]
xs.sort(reverse=True)
```

Here's how you can do it for all three of your random values, using `zip` to get one value from each list:

```
a_list = [random.randrange(0, 50) for _ in range(4)]
b_list = [random.randrange(0, 50) for _ in range(4)]
c_list = [random.randrange(0, 812) for _ in range(4)]

a_list.sort(reverse=True)
b_list.sort(reverse=True)
c_list.sort(reverse=True)

for ipca, ipcb, ipcc in zip(a_list, b_list, c_list):
    distance = math.sqrt(ipca*ipca + ipcb*ipcb + ipcc*ipcc)
    # ...
```

Comment: its not worked in my program.;(

ipca=[random.randrange(0, 50) for _ in range(4)]
        ipcb=[random.randrange(0, 50) for _ in range(4)]
        ipcc=[random.randrange(0, 812) for _ in range(0)]
        ipca.sort(reverse=True)
        ipcb.sort(reverse=True)
        ipcc.sort(reverse=True)








        #3D space distance calculation
        #idstance= math.sqrt((icba-ipca)**2 + (icbb-ipcb)**2 + (icbc-ipcc)**2)

     
        print "You have enoph fuel to get to New York AirPort"
        print ipca,ipcb,ipcc
              

 AirPort please go to the nearest one or you will die"

Comment: @user1968771 I've updated my answer to show how you can loop over the three lists together. I'm not absolutely certain if this is what you want (all three numbers will be always decreasing, which isn't strictly required if you just want decreasing distances). You may want to think about exactly what sort of random distribution your program really needs.

Answer (score 1):

You already control the maximum value, just pass in the last value to get a new value less then that.

```
value = 1000
for x in xrange(10):
    value = random.randrange(value)
    print value
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as @Blender's solution (albeit, without the function wrapped around it), and so my comment there applies here too. Your random values will not be uniformly distributed over the whole range. Consider what would happen if the first random value (from the range 0-999) was 20, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could take your previous random number into account:

```
number = random.randrange(0, 850)

while icounter < 4:
    if number == 0:
        print 'Number is zero'
        break

     number = random.randrange(0, number)
```

If you need a uniform distribution, you'd have to use something like this:

```
def random_numbers(n=6, minimum=0, maximum=850):
    numbers = [random.randrange(minimum, maximum) for i in xrange(n)]
    numbers.sort(reverse=True)

    return numbers
```

Comment: This will give a non-uniform distribution, which may or may not be what the questioner wants.

Comment: @Blckknght: Thanks, I've added that into my answer.